# check which ids exists postgrestable

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

What is a fast of checking which ids exist in postgreSQL table

I wrote the following function but it comes very slow when `len(x)` is bigger than 500 000

```
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect(...)
cursor = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)

def check_exist(lst):
    exist = []
    not_exist = []
    for i in lst:
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM table1 where id={i}")
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        if row:
            exist.append(i)
        else:
            not_exist.append(i)
    return exist, not_exist

x, y = check_exist(['2','4','3000','50000','10000000'])
```

Comment: Why are you checking whether an ID exists in the database from Python in the first place?

Comment: Anyway, yes, you're doing 500,000 `SELECT *` queries for 500,000 IDs. It's going to be slow. This is almost certainly an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627). If you explain what you are trying to accomplish we can probably recommend a better approach.

Comment: @Chris I am writing a script that should create 2 tables based on user input, the user input in my model will get me a list of ids (Ideally the user will select a max of 10000 ids) but I want to make it faster, so I am looking for better ways of doing it

Comment: "the user input in my model will get me a list of ids"—why? What do you want to do with these IDs?

Comment: @Chris Maybe I should have mentioned that is for Django app, where the user will submit a form (select items), the submission will generate a list of IDs, the IDs needs to be checked if exist in table-> if yes then the item is in stock else out of stock finally
items that the user selected will be displayed on 2 different webpages

Comment: ...I have so many questions about this. Where do the IDs come from in the first place? Are users typing in numbers? Looking things up? Why would anybody ever submit _10-500k items in one form?_ Why does "in stock" equal "the ID exists"? Shouldn't ID existence and stock be different things? You definitely, definitely, have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627) as I suggested earlier. Please zoom way out and rethink what you are trying to accomplish. If you explain that we might be able to help, but it also might be way too broad for SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [ANY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html) and let Postgres do most of the work:

```
import psycopg2, time
# database is in a datacenter just using a tunnel!
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=mf port=5959 host=localhost user=mf_usr")
cur = conn.cursor()

ids = [x for x in range(0, 750000)]

sql = """
    SELECT array_agg(id) from __users where id = ANY(%s);
"""
# array_agg: Postgres returns an array of ids!

_start = time.time()
cur.execute(sql, (ids, ))
existingIds = cur.fetchone()[0]
missingIds = set(ids) - set(existingIds)

print(len(existingIds))
print(len(missingIds))
print('Took: %.6f seconds' % (time.time() - _start))
```

Out:

```
284365
465635
Took: 5.564851 seconds
```

**Note:** Make sure to have an index on the ID column

Comment: exactly what I asked for, by the way, you can use `ids = list(range(750000))`

Comment: I still think this was an XY problem, but I guess you answered what OP asked.

Comment: @goku: I always forget about that :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the IN clause. Create a list with your IDs. Iterate the list in your application to verify what IDs doesn't figure in the found records list.

Select id from table1 where id IN ( [your list] )

A point: querying less fields from table makes your query more efficient.

Comment: An `IN` clause with 500,000 entries probably isn't a great idea, either. OP has an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627), and we need to learn more about what they are trying to do before we can offer good advice.

Comment: I do not care what is in the row at moment, I am just checking to see if id exists or not.
I will use the ID in a later function